cooperative games, shapley and additivity
I am studying Shapley values and am interested in understanding cases where additivity does not hold in cooperative games. Specifically, I am looking for a practical example of two cooperative games defined by characteristic functions $v$ and $g$ where for a coalition $Q$, the following inequality holds:
$$
(v + g)(Q) \neq v(Q) + g(Q)
$$
Could you please provide a concrete example of such cooperative games? I would appreciate a detailed description of the characteristic functions $v$ and $g$, and how the values of the coalitions are calculated to show that additivity does not occur.
